How to add maxRetries to solana-py send_transaction
I send tx with Python SDK send_transaction function.
ctx = Client(RPC_URL, commitment=Commitment("confirmed"))
txn = ctx.send_transaction(tx, *signers)

I want to add to send tx process maxRetries option like with sendTransaction RPC Method Solana API: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/sendtransaction
How to make that correctly?

The param definitely exists on the optional TxOpts that can be passed to send_transaction: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/ff9af6800293b7fda8f542c7da8e5b329e7ec342/src/solana/rpc/types.py#L72
I haven't tested this, but you should be able to do something like:
txn = ctx.send_transaction(tx, *signers, opts=TxOpts(max_retries=10))


Thank you! I'll try it tomorrow
